# Store jpg to MongoDB in Symfony2

Tags: image, mongodb, symfony, store

I want to save `img\uglyTrollFaceSizeS.jpg` `img\uglyTrollFaceSizeM.jpg` `img\uglyTrollFaceSizeL.jpg` `img\uglyTrollFaceSizeXXXXL.jpg` to MongoDB and then get single filename in `Command\TrollImageCommand.php` to variable `$filename` in `foreach`. But I do not get how to do that correct way.

Comment: See this post http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/10/uploading-files-to-mongodb-gridfs-2/

Comment: Images are stored on hard drive, I want to upload file from directory in Command, and do not want to get from POST method in Controller

Comment: Are you using PHP's MongoDB-driver or a library like DoctrineODM?

Comment: use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB; Is that what you mean?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/storing-files-with-mongogridfs.html